# How to transfer materials on object from material indices in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I am trying to pass thru some tutorial from youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uv8FzbaxAw0
At 15:30 the author said that currently (7 Jun. 2018) Animation nodes cant work properly with material indices in version 2.1 of Animation Nodes. The question is how I can transfer materials from meshes to combined one from material indices? Thank you!
blend file is here:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3ytg/2FJmrP6hV

[image: Animation Nodes node tree]
[image: there is no different materials]
[image: different materials]